# Adding ImageButton to specific position in Android

Tags: android, imagebutton

I am very novice to android and trying to add a `ImageButton` at specific position of my first android app but i am getting `image rectangular box`  start from the start of the screen whereas my button image is at right place ..Here is my code..

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:background="@drawable/pnr_bg"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:padding="0dp" >

<ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/imageButton1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:paddingLeft="50dp"
    android:paddingTop="100dp"
    android:src="@drawable/normal" />
```

Why is this rectangular box visible from the start of the application screen .Please help me..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since u r using `LinearLayout`it fill from the Top to bottom so if u have one View inside the Laytout, it will be at the Top of the Application Screen.
in order to use Relative location on the Screen
change the `LinearLayout`to `RelativeLayout`

here is an Example :

[Button Center Screen](http://www.mkyong.com/android/android-how-to-center-button-on-screen/)

instand of using

```
android:paddingLeft="50dp" 
android:paddingTop="100dp"
```

use

```
android:layout_marginLeft="50dp" 
android:layout_marginTop="100dp"
```

Comment: Sir t tried to change to RelativeLayout of my same code but result is same only

Comment: in ur question u didnt state where do u want the button to be so i gave a general answer and a common example if u give me a position i will give u code

Comment: i have to place button at 50dp and 100dp